# Slow webservice invocation from Weblogic 12c

Tags: jax-ws, weblogic12c

I am facing a strange problem, I have a weblogic 12c server running on a jdk 1.6.0_25 I am consuming a webservice that's protected over SSL.

My problem is that first call takes 5 seconds while other calls when done quickly take only 500 milliseconds (the actual number the invocation takes when called from a regular J2SE application) when I leave the server uncalled for 3 seconds or more the latency returns back.

I tried deploying the application over an Apache Tomcat 7 and the invocation takes 500 milliseconds all the time.

I checked the JAX-WS RI for both servers is the same 2.1.6.

Any clue about why is this slowdown happening?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. I found the solution..

The slowdown was coming from resolving the IP address of the webservice.. because I was using an Ip address.

I am using windows so I solved it by adding a resolution entry in the file:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

as:

213.123.123.123 local.dnsentry.ps

And that's it.. :-)